# Googlemap engine on html page

Tags: google-maps-api-3, dictionary

Can someone give me some idea to embed googlemap engine on page so that it should point position with some symbol for input entered

I want page to be like this

```
 ----------------------------
 |                          |
 |                          |
 |      Google map here     |
 |                          |
 |                          |
 ----------------------------

 Enter Latitude  Box [       ]
 Enter Longitude Box [       ]

     [ SUBMIT Button ]
```

I will tell you guys frankly I really don't have experience in this, if someone can give sample code for above mentioned one I can play with it... please do needful... I would like to learn it... please help me..

I have installed php and mysql on centos 6.4 if I get some samples I will understand early.. please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to grab an api key for google maps.
Then you need to implement the map using html and javascript.

Take a look at google's documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial
There are some code samples as well.

Comment: You don't have to use an API key

Comment: well without the API key you can simply load in the API js file like `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>`

Comment: @peter read this mate https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial#api_key